# Select2, bootstrap. Al hacer varias búsquedas da error de js y muestra opciones no validas

Tags: bootstrap, select2, buscador

Estoy haciendo una consulta y me presenta peculiaridad, a ver si a alguien le sucedió.

Quiero usar el **`select2`**, de la manera mas simple le pongo al `select` la clase y en `js` pongo:

```
$('.select2').select2();
```

El `select` lo relleno con un `select * from` comun de `sql server`

Cuando realizo muchas búsquedas en el mismo select se tilda y muestra este:

> "Searching..."

Si a alguno le pasó agradecería mucho que me comenten como lo solucionaron así no tengo que recurrir a un buscador distinto.

Gracias!!!!

CODIGO: Estoy haciendo una web sencilla con php puro por eso hago la consulta directamente así

```
$sql_locomotora = "select id,numero from MaterialRodante where IdTipoMaterialRodante=1 and EstaOperativo=1 and Numero not like '%movil%' order by Numero";
$stmt_locomotora = sqlsrv_query( $con_material, $sql_locomotora);       
if( $stmt_locomotora === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
while($locomotora = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt_locomotora)){
    $locomotoras[]= '<option id="'.$locomotora['id'].'" value="'.$locomotora['id'].'" >'.$locomotora['numero'].'</option>';
}
```

Y luego hago un print en el select que le pongo la clase:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Locomotora</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 80px;" id="locomotora" name="locomotora">
                <?php
                print_r($locomotoras);
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: select2error]

Agrego el error como texto:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at select2.js:2
    at Function.map (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at select2.js:2
    at n.current (select2.js:2)
    at r.setClasses (select2.js:2)
    at d. (select2.js:2)
    at d.e.invoke (select2.js:2)
    at d.e.trigger (select2.js:2)
    at d.trigger (select2.js:2)
    at d. (select2.js:2)**

Comment: Posiblemente sea que alguno de tus datos que mandas poner al select no trae valor desde la BD, por eso te marca undefined.

Comment: No creo que sea eso, ya que cuando le saco la clase select2 los datos vienen todos y no trae mas ese error. Salvo que la clase de alguna manera esté haciendo que los datos se conviertan en indefinidos.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta la encontre usando CHOSEN de bootstrap, me parece mucho mas fiel.

[La documentación para poder usarla esta acá y es bastante fácil](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Gracias!!